# Strange htaccess Problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website with this in the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

#DirectoryIndex index.php
```

My problem is even, if I change a single letter the website is rendering a 500 Error. Even if I empty complete file, it still shows me the 500 Error.

What I want to do is, there is a page like this on the domain
http://www.example.co.uk/brochure/generate.php

The file `generate.php` does exist in `/brochure/` directory.

But still the `generate.php` does not load and it is loading the `index.php` file.

Any help?

Comment: Check your apache error log, it might contain valuable clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following which I know should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Turn the Rewrite Engine ON
    RewriteEngine On

    #Set the base where to rewrite the requests
    RewriteBase /

    #Allow direct file access
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    #Allow direct directory access
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #Disallow certain files.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !brochure\/generate\.php$

    #Rewrite URLS To GET[menu] and make sure this is the last rule.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you do not see any rewriting taking palce then check to see the module for rewrite is installed.

Comment: Hey Robert, my point is that it is rewriting `brochure/generate.php` to `index.php` which I do not want to. How do I exclude that?

Comment: Doesn't work. Now that should be the problem with mod_rewrite correct?

Answer (score 0):

If an *empty* file triggers a 500 status code as well, then the error is somewhere else: you are not editing the real `.htaccess` file being used by Apache, the error comes from the application, etc.

In any case, you should find the error log: that's where the exact details are shown. In Linux, it's normally under `/var/log/httpd`. In Windows, it can be under `%ProgramFiles%\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs`. If it's a shared hosting account, you'll probably have an "Errors" or "Logs" feature in your control panel.

Comment: The empty .htaccess file triggers an error, where as my .htaccess file do not. Isn't this strange? Also when I see the Cpanel error logs, its empty.